# Dropping into NSBox subclass doesn't work

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I have created NSBox subclass to implement drag-and-drop. I followed [this](https://www.appcoda.com/nspasteboard-macos/) tutorial. Code looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class EditCard: NSBox, NSDraggingSource, NSPasteboardItemDataProvider, NSPasteboardWriting  {
        
    var value: String = "0"

    let supportedTypes: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] = [.string]
    
        func highlight() {
            self.borderColor = NSColor.controlAccentColor
            self.borderWidth = 2.0
        }

        func unhighlight() {
            self.borderColor = NSColor.clear
            self.borderWidth = 0.0
        }
    
        override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
            let canReadPasteboardObjects = sender.draggingPasteboard.canReadObject(forClasses: [NSString.self], options: nil)
            
            if canReadPasteboardObjects {
                highlight()
                return .copy
            }
             
            return NSDragOperation()
        }
    
        override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
            sender.draggingDestinationWindow?.orderFrontRegardless()
            
            guard let pasteboardObjects = sender.draggingPasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSString.self], options: nil), pasteboardObjects.count > 0 else { return false }
            
            pasteboardObjects.forEach { (object) in
                //Add both views to group
            }
            
            sender.draggingDestinationWindow?.orderFrontRegardless()
            return true
        }
    
        override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) {
            unhighlight()
        }
     
        override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
            unhighlight()
        }
    
        override func concludeDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
            highlight()
        }
    
        override func prepareForDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, sourceOperationMaskFor context: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
            return .copy
        }
        
        func pasteboard(_ pasteboard: NSPasteboard?, item: NSPasteboardItem, provideDataForType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) {
            
            switch type {
            case .string:
                guard let indexData = value.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
                    item.setData(indexData, forType: type)
                default: break
            }
        }
        
        func writableTypes(for pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] {
            var types = [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType]()
            types.append(.string)
             
            return types
        }
        
        func pasteboardPropertyList(forType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) -> Any? {
            return nil
        }
    
        override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
            let pasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
            pasteboardItem.setDataProvider(self, forTypes: [.string])
            
            let pdfData = self.dataWithPDF(inside: self.bounds)
            let imageFromPDF = NSImage(data: pdfData)
            
            let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: pasteboardItem)
            draggingItem.setDraggingFrame(self.bounds, contents: imageFromPDF)

            beginDraggingSession(with: [draggingItem], event: event, source: self)
        }
        
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            self.wantsLayer = true
            self.registerForDraggedTypes(supportedTypes)
        }
}
```

I want to have this view to work both ways. Dragging this view works, but other views of the same subclass don't highlight when putting dragged view over it. When I try to `print()` on any function that accepts dragging (draggingEntered(), performDragOperation(), etc) nothing prints. Can somebody help me?

Comment: NSBox contains a view (`NSView`).  Make a subclass as a drop box.

Comment: @Willeke NSBox also conforms to DraggingDestination protocol so I thought that this will work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, `NSBox` should work. I tried your code (on 10.15) and the `NSDraggingDestination` methods are called. I put two `EditCard`s in the view of the view controller of the default storyboard.

Comment: @Willeke I tried and it works when I added it in a separate project. However, in my app, I add this programmatically to ViewController like that (next comment) and it doesn't work so that means that it's something here.

Comment: https://snippet.host/sper

Comment: El Tomato is right, the box contains a view. A box created in IB doesn't.